# Inheritance Use? General Programming

Tags: java, computer-science

I'm a beginner programmer ( Currently using Java ) and I'm practicing classes, objects, and inheritance/Polymorphism. I'm confused on the whole idea of what is useful when it comes to Polymorphism. Let me give you an example of a fighting arcade game like Mortal Kombat. If you make a class called Fighter with variables and methods of setting the health, getting health, moves, etc. Then you go to your main class and create an object that would be something like `Fighter Scorpion = new Fighter();` Then you could just create many other objects off the same Fighter class. `Fighter Cobra = new Fighter();` or `Fighter Subzero = new Fighter();` and then you would just access the methods through the seperate Fighter class objects (The fighters ) like so,

```
Subzero.setHealth(100);
Subzero.SetShield(200);
Subsero.Move(punch);

Scorpion.SetHealth(200);

...
```

How would you come of use to the subject of inheritance? From what I've read, I believe it's used to do the same type of thing but instead, set specifics to that class instead of all the objects having the same methods and such. Such as in my example, you create a new Scorpion class that's derived from the Fighter class which then you could add a ScorpionAttack method specific to the Scorpion class. So you could do something like so...

```
 Scorpion.setHealth(200); // From the main Fighter class
 Scorpion.ScorpionAttack; // From the specific derived class Scorpion
```

I don't know if I'm quite understanding the whole idea of inheritance and how it becomes useful. My complete question is am I completely correct on the idea of inheritance or am I missing a point to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main idea on your example is that `Fighter` can have a method `attack()`, but in each subclass you'd have a different implementation. For example, Scorpion would throw his spear and Subzero would do his freeze stuff.

Comment: The idea is that when you get a `Fighter` variable, you know you can use its `attack` method, even if you do not know exactly *how* it does it. Of course, it is expected that `Fighter` defines a **contract** that specifies what is *what* `attack` does, and the implementations should follow that contract.

Answer (score 1):

Think about the graphic rendering of the screen in a game like Mortal Kombat. There are a lot of elements that must be drawn: scoreboard, health bars, timer, background, foreground, fighters, etc.
At some level of abstraction each fighter is also a "Drawable", just like the other interface elements and might have a specific method for drawing itself.

Inheritance is a way to model "IS-A" relations so that you have more and more general abstractions to use in some parts of the programs. See the Liskov substitution principle to get an idea of the benefits and constraints of this.

Inheritance can also be used for reusing code: a method Drawable.drawLine() could be used by many different classes.

Polymorphism is a feature of object oriented languages that makes it easy to dispatch method calls to many different code paths depending on the runtime class of the specific object upon which the method is called. Think of it as a way of transforming:

```
(pseudocode)
subzero.draw() into subzero.getClass().draw(this=subzero) 
// Figher.draw(this=subzero)
healthbar.draw() into healthbar.getClass().draw(this=healthbar) 
// Healthbar.draw(this=subzero)
```

While inheritance will chase implementations in the hierarchy of classes in this way:

```
(pseudocode)
Fighter.draw(this) into 
if Figher class defines method draw(Drawable this)
     execute function code from Fighter.java
else super(Figher).draw(this)
```

Where super(Class) gets the class one step up the inheritance hierarcy.

Answer (score 0):

Look it as this:

Think in terms of real world objects(its Object Oriented :))

You have a Vehicle class.

3 other classes : Truck, Bus and Car inherit from Vehicle(inherit some behaviors)

Using polymorphism (method overriding) you can override the default behavior of the parent class(Vehicle here).

So now when you call horn() method on Vehicle(provided you use Vehicle as the reference variable....) you can make a Car peep peeeep, bus pom pom pmmmm....different implementations of the parent method in its subclasses, and the methods are called dynamically depending upon the object type at runtime.